# How to solve the dependency error of tawk to chat npm package with react 18.1.0?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-dom, tawk.to

I am trying to install tawk to chat npm package from https://github.com/tawk/tawk-messenger-react. But I get the following error as attached below. I fear if I choose to install it forcefully, it will mess up my code-base. How can I solve it?

error log URL- https://termbin.com/4q35

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: laptop-warehouse@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react-dom@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-dom@"^17.0.2" from @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react
npm ERR!   @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/somaya/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/somaya/.npm/_logs/2022-05-07T19_08_49_501Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react@` package isn't compatible with react-dom 18. Try using `react-dom@"^17.0.2"`

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm install <dependencyName> --force` or `npm install <dependencyName> --legacy-peer-deps`

if that doesnt work remove node modules and install packages again

if that also doesnt work then you will have to downgrade your `react` and `react-dom` versions

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react 18.1.0 you should use `@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react@2.0.1`

Base on the error you provide you are using `@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react@1.0.0` which supports react 17 and conflict on version you are using.

Our messenger version `1.*.*` is supporting **react 17**
and version `2.*.*` for supporting **react 18**